# HTML doesn't recognize tags in strings saved on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to show some data that I get from textarea tag and saved it in mongodb.
When i try to show it with the `<br/>` tag the html just show it like this and doesn't show a new line:

```
Review about the short animation film 'PUAL':<br /><br /> "First, Congratulations! A very well <br /><br /> thought out piece. The sound design
```

The template code is the following:

```
<div>
  <p> <%= person.quoteEng%></p>
</div>
```

The controller code is the following:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
  // Get all projects from DB 
  Person.find({})(function(err, allperson){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   } else {     
     res.render("feedback/index",{persons: allperson});
   }
});
```

and the code to get text from the form is a very simple controller:

```
router.post("/",middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
  var quoteEng = req.body.quoteEng;
  var NewPerson = { quoteEng: quoteEng}
  Person.create(NewPerson, function(err, newlyPerson){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log(newlyPerson);
      res.redirect("feedback/0");
    }
  });
});
```

I used nl2br to change /n to

Please, help me.
Thank you

Comment: `<%= person.quoteEng%>` is not HTML. It is some kind of template language. Which template language are you using?

Comment: you meant for this:  var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    quoteEng: String,
}); ?

Comment: I doubt it. `res.render` passes the template string through some template engine. Presumably you have it set up as a middleware or an express config somewhere.

Comment: i use express, mongoose do you mean this?

Comment: the middleware is just function that check if the admin is logged in

Comment: Mongoose is a database. Express is an HTTP framework. You are getting data out of Mongoose, converting it to HTML, then sending it in the HTTP response. What are you using to convert it to HTML? The `render` method is passing the template and the data through the template engine you picked. What is the template engine? http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.engine

Comment: app.set("view engine", "ejs"); I hope that you mean to this

Answer (score 2):

You are using the EJS template language. [Look at the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs):

> Escaped output with `<%= %>` (escape function configurable)

You are using `<%= %>`, so input is being treated as plain text and converted to HTML.

> Unescaped raw output with `<%- %>`

Use that instead. Be careful not to expose yourself to [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS).

Comment: Thank you very much man!
It solved my problem
Can I get more information about this security risk
for example if the attacker can get my username and password of the user that fill up the form?
and how can I protect my site from this?

Comment: "Can I get more information about this security risk" — That's what the link is for.

Comment: "the attacker can get my username and password" — If the site is vulnerable, then that is quite likely.